# Using VBA to find a hyphen within cells in column A and to replace with " "

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and trying to wrap my head around how I can utilize it to speed up inputting of data. The issue that I have is when collating data from external sales figures, product codes can be written with a hyphen or without (ie. PB-123 or PB 123), making my MATCH, LOOKUPS next to obsolete without manual intervention which is taking too much time.

I was wondering if there is a standard excel forumula that can automatically find and replace this hyphen with a space or if I would need to go down the VBA route?

Thank you

Comment: =SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," ") will do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That has worked a treat!

Comment: Shame you don't have access to the external files before they're completed - adding data validation of `=A1=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","")` would throw an error if they typed a hyphen in the cell in the first place.

Comment: @AlexK. -- Your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is another Excel-Function helping you better, but the only function I can think of is

```
=Replace()
```

Here the link to the MS-Help-Site:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/REPLACE-REPLACEB-functions-8d799074-2425-4a8a-84bc-82472868878a

In addition it is very easy to write in vba.

```
For i = 1 to x 'x=the last row
    replace(cells(i,1),"-"," ")
next i
```